# ASP.net swagger API return 200 using curl -I localhost:5100/index.html while returns 404 for localhost:5100?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, swagger

I deployed a ASP.net core swagger API in Azure K8s cluster when im verifying it reaching the main page using curl -I localhost:5100 i got error 404 while when im trying curl -I locolhost:5100/index.html i got the respond 200.

what could be causing this problem knowing this my startup class

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var healthCheckOptions = new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                ResponseWriter = WriteReadinessResponse
            };

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/readiness", healthCheckOptions);
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/liveness", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    Predicate = (_) => false
                });
            });

            // enable swagger support
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
           {
               c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;//all request to route [/] are being forward to index.html somehow
               c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Demo API V1");
           });
        }
```

is there a way how to fix this ? I like to get respond 200 when I curl -I localhost:5100.

Answer (score 0):

[DefaultFilesOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.defaultfilesoptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0) It will redirect for default, if the url route do not  specifies the static file.

Inside your configure method, try:

```
        var defaultFileOptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();
    defaultFileOptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
    defaultFileOptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");

    app.UseDefaultFiles(defaultFileOptions);
```

Comment: The default  url when you run the app is : **localhost:5100/swagger/index.html** ,  i used **c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty** to route **localhost:5100** to **localhost:5100/index.html**, however your solution doesnt solve the problem